# NaNs to Integers

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python/Pandas, and I am attempting to complete a project that requires "binning" by age groups. Following is my code:

```
    #Break age groups into bins of 4 years
# Create the bins in which Data will be held
# Bins are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10   
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    # Create the names for the bins
    group_names = ["Age 7-10", "Age 11-14", "Age 15-18", "Age 19-22", "Age 23-26", "Age 27-30", "Age 31-34", "Age 35-38", "Age 39-42", "Age 43+"]
    df_purchase_data["Player Age Groups"] = pd.cut(df_purchase_data["Age"], bins,     labels=group_names, include_lowest=True)
    df_purchase_data
```

The problem I am having is that this generates a table with important information in the cells, but they are presented as NaN's in my table. I need to use this dataframe to do other calculations, so I need those NaN's to be converted to integers. I have tried all sorts of code whilst searching around to do it, but no matter what I do, they still come out as NaN's. I'm working in Jupyter Notebook, so I made sure to rerun all my blocks of code again in case something got missed, but it's a no-go.

Here is the additional code I have in there right now:

```
# Creating a group based off of the bins/clean data of NaN's
df_age_groups = df_purchase_data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
df_age_groups = df_purchase_data.dropna()
df_age_groups = df_purchase_data.reset_index(drop=True)
df_age_groups = df_purchase_data.groupby("Player Age Groups")

df_age_groups.max()
```

And, it still puts NaNs in 4 columns for the first six bins, even though I've checked the csv and determined there genuinely is data in there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
print(df)

   a
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN

df.fillna(0).astype(int)#fill with zeros and convert  to integer astype

    a
0   0
1   0
2   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` and then cast type to `int`

```
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Replace 0 with any other value, if in other type change `.astype`

Comment: I don't want the value to automatically be a zero, however. I just want it to recognize the number that is in there as an int and not a string. At least I think that's what I need.